# Programmatically join 2 numbers

Tags: blackberry

I have created a simple app (using phonelistener) which listens for an incoming call and when one comes, the app dials another number. Now how do I go about joining the two numbers programmatically (Not manually, for I know how to do it manually) so as to establish a conference call?

e.g. Incoming call number - 092098

```
  Dialled number - 447767
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [EventInjector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventInjector.html) and inject [keyboard events](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventInjector.KeyEvent.html) when it is necessary.

It will emulate user keyboard input and do what you want.

Make sure you [have requested](http://tinyurl.com/d6stf2s) and [set relevant permissions](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html) at the application startup. Otherwise `EventInjector` won't work.

Comment: I am using eventInjectors, but so far I can't get them right, on the simulator they join the calls perfectly but on the device they're erratic and all over the place. I have set permissions in my code to include eventInjectors

Comment: Application behaviour on simulator and or an actual device is different. Sometimes difference is light, but sometimes, especially when complex functionality is involved - it is significant. Do no rely on simulator, it does not show you true picture.

Comment: Thanks, it is kind of tricky to get the correct eventinjectors to fire in the correct order on the actual device, but I'll get there.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider integrating Twilio into your app.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/simple-conference

Comment: How does that conference an _incoming_ call?